# A FIDO U2F Device relies on public/private keys. Do they expire like in regular x509 certificates?

Tags: u2f, fido

A FIDO U2F Device relies on public/private keys. Do they expire like in regular x509 certificates ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they do not expire.  Probably mainly because x509 usually relies on external authority, whereas in FIDO U2F you issue your own pair.